# Why copying lists (which are called by functions) with [:] doesn't work?

Tags: python, arrays, list, copy, pass-by-reference

I have two lists like:

```
prelist = [0, 0, 0, 0, 0]

postlist = [50.0, 25.0, 12.5, 6.25, 3.125]
```

I tried copying the list like so:

```
prelist = postlist[:]
```

but the surrounding code didn't work.
When I copy the list this way instead, I get the desired results:

```
for i in range(5):
    prelist[i] = postlist[i]
```

What is wrong with the first approach?

Comment: Welcome to Stack Overflow. Writing `prelist = postlist[:]` definitely does copy the list. Most likely, the problem is that **other** code that knows about the existing list that `prelist` was already naming, will not be aware of the change - since we created a **new** list that is a copy, rather than modifying the existing `prelist` list. However, there is no way to be specific without a proper [mre]. Please read [ask] and note well that this is **not a discussion forum**; we cannot do exploratory work on your codebase for you.

Comment: @Erme Can you please be more precise about what exactly you tried that didn't work out? It would help if you could write a short function that we can try out that leads to the same behavior

Comment: I [edit]ed the question to remove everything that is irrelevant. The next step is to add the things that are missing: What is the surrounding code that didn't work? What was supposed to happen, and what happened instead? Especially since you acknowledge that you are a bit out of your depth, it is very important to **show, don't tell nor guess** - descriptions like "called into a function", aside from not being sensible uses of the terminology, are not adequate descriptions.

Comment: Thank you for your advices Karl. I wasn't trying to make somebody else work on my codebase, I was just trying to understand why it works like that. But I understand that I gave lacking information so I understand that's why it's hard for people to explain to me what's the problem or is there a problem at all. I will try my best to ask better questions in the future. I was frustrated with this problem as I've been trying to solve this little issue for the last 4 hours. I will try to be more explanatory in the future.

Answer (score 0):

When `A` and `B` refer to two lists, `B = A[:]` means make a copy of the list `A` refers to, then make `B` refer to the new copy of `A` instead of the list it used to refer to. The list `B` used to refer to is completely unaffected. That list exists independently of the `B` variable, and is not involved in this operation at all.

It sounds like you were looking for `B[:] = A`, which copies the contents of `A` *into* the existing list `B` refers to, instead of making a new list.

(Note that the `[:]` slicing means different things on the left and right sides of the assignment. On the right side, evaluating `A[:]` as an expression creates a new list. On the left side, assigning to `B[:]` copies elements into an existing list.)

Comment: This seems likely to answer the underlying problem, once the question has the appropriate information added; but in this case it seems likely to be a duplicate. Surely we already have something explaining what `B[:] = A` does and how to use it? Given how fundamental that is?

Comment: @KarlKnechtel: Perhaps, but just explaining what `B[:] = A` does doesn't really do a good job of clearing things up. I think it's important to clearly explain what both `B = A[:]` and `B[:] = A` do, and highlight the difference. The generic dupe targets I usually see for slice-related questions don't do an effective job of clearing up specific misunderstandings.

Comment: There *can't possibly* be as many distinct "specific misunderstandings" as we get questions on this topic. We desperately need to figure out proper canonicals. (Anyway, I think the misunderstanding here isn't about slicing at all; it's about Python's assignment semantics and more generally about "reference semantics".)